# Merge two dataframes keep all rows from left dataframe and merge value of one column from right dataframe to same column in first dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am new to python. Could anyone help me how to merge these table to get the expected result.

Table 1:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   mm  nn  oo  12
2   aa  bb  cc  12
3   xx  yy  zz  12
4   jj  kk  ll  12
5   rr  ss  tt  12
6   gg  hh  ii  12
```

Table 2:

```
A   B   C   D   E
2   aa  bb  cc  5
3   xx  yy  zz  5
4   jj  kk  ll  5
```

Result:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   mm  nn  oo  12
2   aa  bb  cc  5
3   xx  yy  zz  5
4   jj  kk  ll  5
5   rr  ss  tt  12
6   gg  hh  ii  12
```

`pd.merge(df1,df2,how = "left")`

where do I mention about column E in code?

Comment: Use `df1.set_index(['A','B','C','D'], inplace=True)`
`df1.update(df2.set_index(['A','B','C','D']))`
`df = df1.reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the column for the `merge` and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) afterwards:

```
out = pd.merge(df1.drop(columns='E'), df2, how='left').combine_first(df1)
```

Or [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) if you want to modify `df1` in place:

```
df1.update(pd.merge(df1.drop(columns='E'), df2, how='left'))
```

Output:

```
   A   B   C   D     E
0  1  mm  nn  oo  12.0
1  2  aa  bb  cc   5.0
2  3  xx  yy  zz   5.0
3  4  jj  kk  ll   5.0
4  5  rr  ss  tt  12.0
5  6  gg  hh  ii  12.0
```

Comment: It worked on jupyter notebook, but on Visual studio I am getting error: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: which error? Also are you sure you have the same pandas versions? (which ones?)

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
What if I don't want to change the version and keep the older version. Is there any workaround. ?

Comment: Which one is triggering the error? Can you also run the commands separately to identify the culprit?

Comment: Version is same 1.3.4. Type is dataframe for both. Stuck with TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: please run `df1.drop(columns='E')`, `pd.merge(df1.drop(columns='E'), df2, how='left')` and `pd.merge(df1.drop(columns='E'), df2, how='left').combine_first(df1)`, which one(s) trigger the error?

Comment: It got resolved there was dictionary as part of one column. converted it using .astype(str)
Problem was with .merge() function since i was providing dictionary as one column.